# Get NSDecimalNumber with 2 decimal places

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I want to create NSDecimalNumber after dividing 100. I am using following code:

```
NSDecimalNumber *amountToSendNumber = [number decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"]];
```

It gives me correct value if I provide input as 2536 as 25.36. 
But if I provide input as 2500 then output is 25.
I want output as 25.00 without having any rounding off mechanism.

Any Help?

Comment: Your question sounds related to presentation of the number (in a label, for example), however I don't see any presentation code.  Please clarify.

Comment: check NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];

Comment: I want to use NSDecimalNumber instead of float as there are other operations to perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `NSNumberFormatter` while you display a `NSDecimalNumber`

```
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
  [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
   NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
  [formatter setLocale:usLocale];
  NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:amountToSendNumber]);
```

Comment: It is giving me 25,00 instead of 25.00. Can you help me?

Comment: @iAsh (and others) The decimal output format depends on which identifier you use when you init `NSLocal`. With @"en_US" you should get 25.00, but if you use @"sv_SE" for example, you'll get 25,00.

Comment: Is this really the best way to do it? Is there any advantage of using NSDecimalNumber?

Comment: I have requirement to pass NSnumber as 12.00 to json dictionary.
for the cases, 12.32 then all good.
for the cased, 12.00 then it returns NSnumber 12 
Please advise @bhumit mehta